# How can I use google translate directly on sveltekit web pages

Tags: javascript, svelte, google-translate, sveltekit, web-frameworks

I've been having issues using google translator directly on my sveltekit web app using the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function googleTranslateElementInit() {
          new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
        }
  // googleTranslateElementInit()
     </script>
```

I've tried several approaches, for example putting the code in `<svelte:head></svelte:head>` but yet it's kept appearing and disappearing.
Please how can I achieve this,
Note I'm using Static adapter, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to load the script manually after mounting of component. It works with SvelteKit too.

```
onMount(() => {
loadTranslate()
setTimeout(function () {
    googleTranslateInit()
}, 3000)
})
function googleTranslateInit() {
    const checkIfGoogleLoaded = setInterval(() => {
        if (google != null && google.translate != null && google.translate.TranslateElement != null) {
            clearInterval(checkIfGoogleLoaded)

            googleTranslateElementInit()
        }
    }, 1000)
}

function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en' }, 'google_translate_element')
}
function loadTranslate() {
    loading = true
    if (browser) {
        const domElement = document.createElement('script')
        domElement.setAttribute('src', '//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js')
        domElement.onload = () => {
            loadedTranslate = true
        }
        document.body.appendChild(domElement)
    }
}
</script>

<template>
    <div id="google_translate_element" class="mb-2"></div>
</template>
```

Comment: https://github.com/candidosales/svelte-google-translate

`npm i @candidosales/svelte-google-translate`